# Haskell.Network.URI.outside US-ASCII characters

Tags: haskell, encoding, uri

I have the problem to construct URI to make http request via [HTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.1.1) library.

For example:

`import Network.URI`

```
parseURI "http://мтс.рф"
```

or

```
parseURI "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Титова+42&sensor=false"
```

In both cases i have "Nothing". 
I did not find the solution in documentation

I was trying to decode/escape non ASCII characters but does not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second case can be resolved with the utf8-string package:

```
import Network.URI
import Codec.Binary.UTF8.String
uri = parseURI $ (escapeURIString isUnescapedInURI . encodeString)
        "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Титова+42&sensor=false"

main = print uri
```

For the first, try Data.Text.IDN.IDNA.toASCII from the gnuidn package.